# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name' - when i want to select dropdown from Selenium POM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

I'm currently trying to select an index from the dropdown menu using POM in Selenium but I am getting the following error.
Next I would like to build functions for selecting by value and visible text.

Thank you in advance.

**BasePage.py** - here is where I store my generic actions

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def do_select_by_index(self, by_locator, index):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        Select(by_locator).select_by_index(index)
```

**HeaderPage.py** - here is whera I want to perform Select action on MENU_SELECT item

```
from Pages.BasePage import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Header(BasePage):
    
MENU_SELECT = By.ID, ("Form_submitForm_NoOfEmployees")

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def select_menu_index(self):
        self.do_select_by_index(self.MENU_SELECT, 4)
```

**BaseTest - test_base.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

**Test_Select - actual test**

```
from Tests.test_base import BaseTest
from Pages.HeaderPage import Header

class Test_Select(BaseTest):

    def test_selectMenu(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.orangehrm.com/orangehrm-30-day-trial")
        self.header = Header(self.driver)
        self.header.select_menu_index()
```

**Actual results of the test:**

```
self = <Tests.test_1.Test_Select object at 0x0000024B1AD77F70>

    def test_selectMenu(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.orangehrm.com/orangehrm-30-day-trial")
        self.header = Header(self.driver)
>       self.header.select_menu_index()

Tests\test_1.py:9:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
Pages\HeaderPage.py:13: in select_menu_index
    self.do_select_by_index(self.MENU_SELECT, 4)
Pages\BasePage.py:11: in do_select_by_index
    Select(by_locator).select_by_(index)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x0000024B1AD8C040>, webelement = ('id', 'Form_submitForm_NoOfEmployees')

    def __init__(self, webelement):
        """
        Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not,
        then an UnexpectedTagNameException is thrown.

        :Args:
         - webelement - element SELECT element to wrap

        Example:
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select \n
            Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")).select_by_index(2)
        """
>       if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
E       AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py:36: AttributeError
======================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================
FAILED Tests/test_1.py::Test_Select::test_selectMenu[chrome] - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Comment: Well, you have defined `MENU_SELECT ` as a tuple, but `Select` expects a web element, so this is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code in the class BasePage in this way and it works

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def do_select_by_index(self, by_locator, index):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        Select(element).select_by_index(index)
```